# Is an intrinsic lock the same thing as a permit? (Semaphores, locks, threading...)

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, semaphore

I was reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html about  intrinsic locks and semaphores, but then read some http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html about permits - all used with the terminology, "release" and "acquire".

I was wondering if these terms are essentially the same.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I was really focusing on permits vs locks and how they related, but meh. I have a better understanding now.

Comment: quickly google-ing it up will yield the answer...
https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+lock+and+semaphore&aq=0&oq=the+difference+betwen+locks+and+s&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3.19815&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: My questions is about _permits_ vs. locks, not semaphores vs locks... 
and I thought that this was a valid question and wouldn't deserve getting downvoted so much :/ I'm just learning this and have a vague understanding

Answer (score 1):

Semaphores and Locks are similar in that they both allow you to modify your code so that it is thread-safe.  The difference is that, when using a semaphore, you can say something to the effect of "up to two threads can grab this lock at one time"; with a lock you can only allow one thread to grab the lock in all cases.

Comment: +1 The intrinsic lock also releases the the permit implicitly on a wait() or when it goes out of scope. The deadlock detector can also detect when two or more threads are waiting for each other to release a lock. i.e. it has more language and run time support.